# Mac is slower and has strange nuances in operation after liquid contact

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I need some advice with my MBP late 2011 model (13″ Intel i5, 2.4 GHz, 500 GB HDD, 4 GB RAM).

It all started one day when was a heavy rain which went through my windows. I had my Mac on my bed and my bed was completely soaked.

I wiped off the rain water on my Mac and when I powered it on it didn't turn on. I had to press and hold the power button until it came back to life.

**Observations afterwards**

1. Each time I have to turn on my mac, I have to press and hold the power button until the sleep light indicator starts blinking then I release it before it turns on.
2. I performed resetting the SMC and it didn't work: http://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201295
3. I also realized that the mac is considerably slower after the rain incident so I upgraded to an 8 GB RAM. However even after the upgrade it's still slow. Much slower
   than my Windows 7 8 GB RAM i5 Acer laptop. I had to download novabench to benchmark their performances for comparison.
4. I also formatted my 500 GB hard drive and perform a clean install of OS X Mavericks since that was what I performed the benchmarks on. The newly installed
   OS together with the 8 GB RAM is still really slow (you can tell from using it and also as indicated by the benchmark result)
5. I have replaced my 500 GB with an old 256 GB running Mavericks and the performance is still poor.

My question is what could possibly be wrong with my mac and how can I get its performace as it was before the rain incident. The 8 GB RAM isn't improving the performance. I am thinking of getting a SSD hoping it will improve the performance but I highly doubt that.

Answer (score 1):

I really think your best option is to take it into an Apple-licensed fix-it person and have them open it up. I expect they'll find some kind of damage on the motherboard (probably up and around the underside & top). Water does some gnarly things to electronics, so just because it's still turning on and 'working' doesn't mean there isn't something damaged on the mobo.